# Django: Save auth_user to model with Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models

The scenario is the following:

I have a Django form which places a post request to the backend. With this data, I create an instance of my order model. One order can have one customer and a customer *can* have one auth_user. Database is SQLite. The relation looks like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class Customer(models.Model):
email = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_TEXT_LENGTH)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I managed to save all of them, order and customer are correctly related in the database. Although I am somehow failing while saving the user to customer. I save them like this in my view.py:

```
            with transaction.atomic():
            # create customer & order
            customer = create_customer(first_name, last_name, email, phone)
            order = create_order(customer, form.cleaned_data)

            # add additional stuff to order
            order.additional_services.add(*form.cleaned_data['additional_service']),
            order.save

            # create user and update customer
            plain_user_password = generatePassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LENGTH)
            user = create_user(order.id, email, plain_user_password, first_name, last_name)

        customer.user = user
        customer.save
```

I create all my models with `Model.objects.create(...)`

Using the order.id as username is a given and cannot be changed. The last two lines seem not to work, although the customer holds the correct user_id afterwards (verified by debugging), the column in the database table is null... No exception occurring when I use a try-catch block either...

What am I missing? Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert

solution: -> customer.save(force_update=True)